# How to fetch data from 3-4 tables of database using Criteria in Hibernate.?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to fetch data from 3-4 tables using "criteria" in hibernate. 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria

Comment: share the code that you have tried. It is possible to perform join in Criteria. If you are facing any issues please share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can join an association by Criteria's createAlias method which needs association path and alias. [Criteria API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)

Comment: Yes, for joining two tables i know...But what about 3-4 tables. How to use 'alias'. i am not aware..It will be good if you post one sample with example.